# What is another solution for v-if in this case?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use v-if in a good way, but so far it looks stupid.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/iTaurus85/pen/OoYYZK)

This is the current piece of code, where I'm trying to choose "icon" depending on the title of the features:

```
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A day' ">close</v-icon>
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A week' ">close</v-icon>
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A month' ">check_circle_outline</v-icon>
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'Forever' ">check_circle_outline</v-icon>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      menuItems:[
        {
          title: 'A day', 
          price: '$50',
          features:['Exercise','Consult','Personal meeting'],
          action: 'check_circle_outline'
        },
        {
          title: 'A week', 
          price: '$200',
          features:['Exercise','Consult','Personal meeting'],
          action: 'check_circle_outline'
        },
        {
          title: 'A month', 
          price: '$500',
          features:['Exercise','Consult','Personal meeting'],
          action: 'check_circle_outline'
        },
        {
          title: 'Forever', 
          price: '$5000',
          features:['Exercise','Consult','Personal meeting'],
          action: 'check_circle_outline'
        }
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

First I tried this:

```
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A day' || 'A week' ">close</v-icon>
<v-icon v-else>check_circle_outline</v-icon>
```

this doesn't work, don't know why.

Can you, please, help to find correct solution to adjust icons depending on the titles?

Comment: item.title === 'A day' || item.title === 'A week'

Comment: you can have an id/name in your data which corresponds to a lowercase non space character eg, week, month etc., and treat that as a class name

Comment: Wrap v-icon with span, eg: ```<span v-if="item.title === 'A day' || 'A week' "><v-icon> close </v-icon></span>```

Comment: @yxf why? I don't see what that improves at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you first tried this:

```
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A day' || 'A week' ">close</v-icon>
<v-icon v-else>check_circle_outline</v-icon>
```

It should be this:

```
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A day' || item.title === 'A week'">close</v-icon>
<v-icon v-else>check_circle_outline</v-icon>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the conditional would go better on the template in this case.  You could pull the regex out to a constant if you want to marginally optimize.

```
// In template
<v-icon>{{ durationText }}</v-icon>

// in component
computed: {
  durationText() {
    const dayOrWeekRegex = /(day|week)/i
    if (dayOrWeekRegex.test(this.title)) return 'close';

    return 'check_circle_outline';
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the proper way to deal with OP's issue

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is the `v-switch-case` directive, [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-switch-case).

```
<div v-switch="item.title">
  <div v-case="'A day'">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might give my solution a try. I'm using the ternary operator along with the mustache syntax like this:

```
  <v-icon> 
    {{
      item.title === 'A day' || item.title==='A week'?
      'close':'check_circle_outline'
    }}
  </v-icon>
```

Those codes replace for:

```
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A day' ">close</v-icon>
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A week' ">close</v-icon>
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'A month' ">check_circle_outline</v-icon>
<v-icon v-if="item.title === 'Forever' ">check_circle_outline</v-icon>
```

I already tested this solution on your codepen, and it worked as expected. Hopefully, you'll like it. Because of its simplicity, btw.